# apple-mobile-web-app-capable breaks flowplayer

Tags: javascript, html, ios, flowplayer, iphone-standalone-web-app

I an trying to convert a site to an iOS web-app. Everything works fine except for Flowplayer - it throws an error as soon as it is run inside a web-app, but is fine in (mobile) Safari.

Test setup:
Downloaded the latest Flowplayer (HTML5 version).
Tested the demo page included in the download in Safari, no problem.
Added `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` to the demo page - error thrown "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.pick')".
I also tried the manual flowplayer init after page load using console in case it was something to do with load order/speed but no joy.

I have the exact problem in my "real" site but this seemed the best way to debug it.

Any idea where to start / how to fix this?

Comment: I just downloaded flowplayer-5.4.3, added `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` to head in index.html, loaded it on an iPad2 with iOS version 6.1.3, added the page to home screen, launched the page as an web app and the demo video loads just fine. So it doesn't seem to be a general problem at least.

Comment: Thanks - but that leaves me a bit stumped... Since 5.4.3 was released today specifically with fixes for UIWebView I wonder if the mobile-web-app setting had somehow cached the JS... I'll try testing on a never before used device.

Comment: @Strille - you're bang on, it was fixed in 5.4.3, but the web-app was (very persistantly) caching the JS. Thanks a lot for pointing me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in 5.4.3 released today - http://flowplayer.org/news/
Flowplayer now works both in web-app mode websites and within an actual app using webView.